# Magento 2 Fatal error when adding date field in admin form and save

Tags: magento2, date

I am developing a custom module where there are many fields text,select,multiselect..etc in admin form.

Today I have added one field in admin of type **time** ,below is the code to add new field

```
$timeFormat = $this->_localeDate->getTimeFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM);

$actionTime = $fieldset->addField(
                    'action_time',
                    'time',
                    [   
                        'name'      => 'action_time',
                        'label'     => __('Time'),
                        'class'     => 'required-entry',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'time_format'=> $timeFormat,
                        'time'=>true
                    ]
                );
```

and in installSchema.php I have put below code to add column in table

```
)->addColumn(
             'action_time',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Action Time'
        )
```

Field created successfully but it throwing error when saving form.
[image]

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php:57
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php(57):
>   DateTime->__construct(Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2764):
>   Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime->formatDate(Array, true) #2
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3001):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->formatDate(Array) #3
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php(183):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareColumnValue(Array,
>   Array) #4
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(541):
>   Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->_prepareDataForTable(Object(Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Grid),
>   'manage_feed_dat...') #5
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework in
>   /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php on
>   line 57

I have debugged but not found any issue.Please help me.

Comment: it could be an issue with the time format, test it with static format like `'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss'` or `'time_format' => 'H:i:s',`

Comment: @magefms, I have also tried this but not working,same error.

Comment: You need to add "default" option with value \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT

Comment: ok @Anju,I am trying now.

Comment: Hi @Anju, this is also not working.

Comment: Did you try new code ?

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM,you mention date in addfield while I require only time.

Comment: may be you are referring the whole object instead of value while saving the form. can you update that part too

Answer (score 0):

first, sorry if my english is bad, i hope u know my ideal.
type time in formfield return array, like  Array [ [0] => 04 , [1] => 20, [2] => 54 
] : 04h:20m:54s. 

 To save  value time field, try it 
 $data['action_time'] = $data['action_time'][0] . ':' . $data['action_time'][1] . ':' .$data['action_time'][2] ;